# How do I solve middleware validation problem in node.js

Tags: express, middleware

I am developing a web page with node.js and express. I am trying to handle the validation using node.js middleware

The web page uses node.js middleware to validate the form, when create post is clicked without user putting any value, the form is expected to reload the same page without performing any action.
I have confirmed that the path to the middleware is correct by putting console.log("middleware works") which printed to the console "middleware works". but putting the code to check user inputs, I get error on the screen

```
'index.js' 
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const Post = require('./database/models/Post');
const fileUpload = require("express-fileupload");
const app = new express();

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/node-js-test-blog', {useNewUrlParser: true })
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(expressEdge);
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(fileUpload());

//this is the middleware that is supposed to check an empty field and return the page posts/new as an empty page. if I remove the code and console.log("middleware works"), it outputs middleware works but on putting the code it generated the error below
module.exports = (req, res, next) => {
if (!req.files.image || !req.body.username || !req.body.title || !req.body.description || !req.body.content) {
    return res.redirect('/posts/new')
}

next()
}


//this is the route to the form page
app.post('/posts/store', (req, res) => {
const { image } = req.files

image.mv(path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/posts', image.name), (error) => {

    Post.create({
        ...req.body,
        image: `/posts/${image.name}`
    }, (error, post) => {
        res.redirect("/");
    });
})
});
app.listen(4000, () => {
console.log("application listening on port 4000")
})
```

}

```
  'the error'
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'image' of null
at module.exports (C:\Users\JERRY\Desktop\NODE-JS-BLOG\middleware\storePost.js:3:20)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\JERRY\Desktop\NODE-JS-BLOG\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at trim_prefix (C:\Users\JERRY\Desktop\NODE-JS-BLOG\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:317:13)
at C:\Users\JERRY\Desktop\NODE-JS-BLOG\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7
at Function.process_params (C:\Users\JERRY\Desktop\NODE-JS-BLOG\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
at next (C:\Users\JERRY\Desktop\NODE-JS-BLOG\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
at Busboy.<anonymous> (C:\Users\JERRY\Desktop\NODE-JS-BLOG\node_modules\express-fileupload\lib\processMultipart.js:82:5)
at Busboy.emit (events.js:208:15)
at Busboy.emit (C:\Users\JERRY\Desktop\NODE-JS-BLOG\node_modules\busboy\lib\main.js:38:33)
at C:\Users\JERRY\Desktop\NODE-JS-BLOG\node_modules\busboy\lib\types\multipart.js:52:13
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:75:11)
```

Comment: check your actually uploading a file, as if you dont that middleware will bork due to not checking req.files and req.body is set too (all your other routes will not be posting or uploading)

Comment: if files is null the middleware also will throw this error, you have to check req.files is not null

Comment: Shouldn't it be `files[0]`?

Comment: thank you it works but I didnt use     files[0]

Comment: I had to add `!req.files` to my already existing validation and the `!req.files.image` too was left untouched and it worked. it is now checking both if no file is added and if no image is selected and it is returning the empty page as expected